# How to read information from core bluetooth device

Tags: ios, ipad, core-bluetooth

I am working on an iOS core Bluetooth application, I am able to connect with the BLE device using iPad3. I am able to reach to the block `didDiscoverServices`, but unable to proceed from here.

My questions are ;

1. How can I read characteristic from Bluetooth device?
2. How can I read other information of Bluetooth device?

Help me on this or provide any suggestion.

Thanks Wilhelmsen for reply.

I got the following from the mentioned block :

```
[0] - Service : <CBConcreteService: 0x1769a0> UUID: Generic Attribute Profile
[1] - Service : <CBConcreteService: 0x174470> UUID: Generic Access Profile
[2] - Service : <CBConcreteService: 0x1744e0> UUID: Unknown (<00005301 00000041 4c505749 53450000>)

Characteristic

[0] - Characteristic : <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x15d410> UUID: Service Changed

[0] - Characteristic : <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x1805b0> UUID: Device Name
[1] - Characteristic : <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x1806a0> UUID: Appearence

[0] - Characteristic : <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x183810> UUID: Unknown (<00004301 00000041 4c505749 53450000>)
[1] - Characteristic : <CBConcreteCharacteristic: 0x1838a0> UUID: Unknown (<00004302 00000041 4c505749 53450000>)
```

Now how to get the exact values from this Characteristic in didUpdateValueForCharacteristic block?

Comment: I edited my answer, but you should create a new question when the old one is solved, and I dont understand much of what you are trying to ask on the updated question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a nice good read through the framework. if you have come this far you shouldn't have any problem finding 'discoverCharacteristics' and the peripheral delegate callback 'didDiscoverCharacteristic'. You need to know the UUID of the services and characteristics you want to discover and apply it to those methods.

Then you can read with 'readValueForCharacteristic' and the delegate callback 'didUpdateValueForCharacteristic'.

This is sent from my phone, so I will maybe edit a bit when I get to a computer. Hope it helps

New question:

```
[connectedPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:wantedCharacteristic]
```

and at peripheral delegate

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"Characteristic value : %@ with ID %@", characteristic.value, characteristic.UUID);
[delegate characteristicValueRead:characteristic.value];
}
```

works for me

Comment: I'm getting characteristic.value = <6fb51600 30cd660e 8c170800>. How can I get exact value from it?

Comment: It is in the way you print it. Try `NSLog(@"value = %@", characteristic.value);` since I think you will get a hex formatted string as output. You could also try %x

Comment: Thanks Wilhelmsen for great reply. Will try it and let you know. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get value of a characteristic

```
 NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Value %@",value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use
https://github.com/LGBluetooth/LGBluetooth

```
    [LGUtils readDataFromCharactUUID:@"f045"
                          seriveUUID:@"5ec0"
                          peripheral:peripheral
                          completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"Data : %s Error : %@", (char *)[data bytes], error);
                          }];
```

Comment: can you help with LGBluetooth!!! i'm trying to write data on charact. but no luck it's always says "wrote data with error: Unknown error"

Comment: try to set a breakpoint in completion block, and print the error object

Comment: Web page unavailable.