# Issue while using Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios

I have to use coreBluetooth to input user weight into app.but i did not find the Bluetooth services and characteristics of the particular device.Please help me to input weight from weight machine into iOS app.Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540812/how-to-read-information-from-core-bluetooth-device

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [LGBluetooth](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/LGBluetooth)

Here is an example of reading data from service "5ec0" and characteristic "f045"

```
        [LGUtils readDataFromCharactUUID:@"f045"
                             serviceUUID:@"5ec0"
                              peripheral:peripheral
                              completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Data : %s Error : %@", (char *)[data bytes], error);
                              }];
```

The connection, also characteristic/service discovery is automatically managed by framework.

I think this will make your job much more easier.